# How I do configure the BigBlueButton module?

Tags: 6

I have installed the [BigBlueButton](https://www.drupal.org/project/bbb) module. Its demo is working fine. How do I create a meeting?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request to a third-party dependency (hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere) and there must be reported to it's issue queue, not here. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem following these steps.

1. Install the module
2. On the module settings page (admin/settings/bigbluebutton), put values for *Server base URL* and *Security salt key*, and save the settings
3. Create a new content type, for example *Conference*
4. On the content type setting panel (for the *Big Blue Button* module), 
   select *Treat this node type as meeting* and *Display meeting status on node*, and save the settings
5. Create a new *Conference* node and go to meeting